# entry level issue: || (OR) operator

Tags: php

When I use the || (OR) operator in my if statement below I end up in an endless loop.

**For sake of simplicity here is the var_dump:**

```
$auth "0" 
$id "2" 
$enabled "1" 
$page "auth-login.php"
```

If the criteria below is not met in the if statement then it will forward the user to auth-login.php (this is not applicable if the current $page is auth-login.php and auth-login-validate.php).

**Statement without || (OR) operator: Forwards to auth-login.php as intended, but must also include auth-login-validate.php**

```
if ($auth == '0' && $id != '1' && $enabled == '1' && $page != 'auth-login.php') {

header('Refresh: 0; URL=auth-login.php');
die();

}
```

**Statement with || (OR) operator: Forwards to auth-login.php endlessly in a loop.**

```
if ($auth == '0' && $id != '1' && $enabled == '1' && $page != 'auth-login.php' || $auth == '0' && $id != '1' && $enabled == '1' && $page != 'auth-login-validate.php') {

header('Refresh: 0; URL=auth-login.php');
die();

}
```

Comment: So you basically have `if (true) redirect to same page` since `$auth==0` by default and user is already on auth-login.php? When using `||` in a longer if, it is usually wise to use paranthesis

Comment: thanks let me try that sorry for the entry level question

Comment: No problem. By the way I just realized that you already have `$auth==0` in this if - so maybe you are trying to do something like `if ( ($id != 1 && .. && ..) || ($auth == 0) )`? It is not clear to me when you want to be in the if and when not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be some precedence related error. Make sure to put the parentheses where you intend to encapsulate the "OR" parts

Comment: *Will be* That sounds like you're not 100% sure for me! *some precedence related error* some? So you don't even know where and which operators? So I think you can improve the quality of your post by showing where and why the error happens

Comment: (a && b && c && d) || (a && b && c && e)
<=> a && b && c && (d || e)
Hope this helps